# 日本語に違和感：「お礼」

Tags: 討議, バグ, 完了, 翻訳

bountyの訳語が「お礼」になっています。stackoverflowのbountyのしくみは、イメージ的には「賞金」、「懸賞ポイント」、「ボーナスポイント」に近いような気がします。

原文：

> What is a bounty? How can I start one?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

現在の日本語：

> お礼とは?どうしたら開始できますか?

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

原文：

> ... you can help by offering a bounty on any question more than two days old.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

現在の日本語：

> 2 日以上経っている質問にお礼を提供してみましょう。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

しっくり来る日本語が思い浮かばない場合は「バウンティ」でよいと思います。「バウンティとは」というページがあるので、そこで説明すれば十分理解されると思います。

Comment: +1: SOでの"bounty"の目的を考えると、「お礼」という訳語には違和感を覚えます。

Comment: +1 バッジの Investor も投資家ですので、「お礼」だと合わないですね。

Comment: 関連: [日本語に違和感: 「おすすめ」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2650)

Answer (score 5):

「賞金」とか「[懸賞](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%87%B8%E8%B3%9E)」もしくは「[謝礼](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%AC%9D%E7%A4%BC)」でどうでしょうか。

Comment: 私は「懸賞」が一番あっているように感じました。

Comment: 「お礼」とか「謝礼」というのは、自分が何か利益を受けてから容易して渡すというイメージが強いので。　予めお礼の額面等が決まっているものとしては私も「懸賞」がいいように思います。　別件で「Investor：投資家」との絡みがコメントで指摘されていたのですが。出てきた回答によって利益を得ていると考えれば問題ないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ふと疑問に思ったので調べたら既に質問があったんですね

個人的には"bounty"であれば、「報酬」が近い気がします。