# 日本語に違和感: 「おすすめ」

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳

トップページにある「おすすめ」タブが、日本語訳から本来の機能のイメージがし辛いです。

「おすすめ」からは『役に立つ質問/回答があります』という印象を個人的に受けますが、
実際には『困っているので助けてください』と回答を募集している段階なはずです。

原語では"bounty"のようなので、「注目」や関連トピックにも挙がっている「懸賞」等の方が
分かりやすいのではないかと思います。

関連： [日本語に違和感：「お礼」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/163/%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ab%e9%81%95%e5%92%8c%e6%84%9f-%e3%81%8a%e7%a4%bc)

Comment: 関連: [未翻訳：質問欄の上のカテゴリー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2923/19110)

Comment: 一律で「懸賞」にしてしまうのはやや無理があって、文脈によっては「懸賞金」のような表現を使い分けてもいいのかな、と思いました。

Answer (score 2):

関連投稿での提案も含め、大きな反対意見も無いため「懸賞」に書き換えをすすめたいと思います。
(もし抜けがあれば編集で追記をお願いします)

---

### 見直しが必要なヘルプページ / string / よくある質問とfaq案

#### ヘルプページ

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty ([改善案反映済み](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3390))
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties ([改善案反映済み](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3391/14055))
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers (反映済み)
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation (反映済み)
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (反映済み)

#### Traducir

- https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=(%3Fi)bounty
- https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=(%3Fi)bounties
- https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=(%3Fi)bountied
- https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=(%3Fi)reward

#### よくある質問とfaq案

- https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2419/14055 (反映済み)
- https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/14055 (反映済み)