# 投稿が削除される仕組みを教えてください

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案, 質問の削除

質問や回答はどういうとき削除されますか？　また、削除されるとどうなるのでしょうか？

- 投稿はどのようにして削除されますか？
- 自分の投稿を削除**できない**のはどんな場合ですか？
- 削除後も自分の投稿を見れますか？
- 削除された自分の投稿一覧を見れますか？
- 自分の投稿の削除を取り消すにはどうすればよいですか？
- 投稿が削除されるとは**実際には**どういうことですか？
- 削除された投稿について他に知っておくべきことは何ですか？
- 削除投票をするとどうなりますか？
- 削除される条件は何ですか？
- もし自分の質問を削除するように通報した場合、どうなりますか？

> その他の情報については、[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)の[「一部の質問が削除される理由とその方法は?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)および[「一部の回答が削除される理由とその方法は?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)をご覧ください。

<sub>(この投稿は、Meta Stack Exchangeへの投稿["How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/)を元にしたものです。英語版に新しい情報が載っているのを見つけたら、是非加筆修正をお願いします。)</sub>

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Comment: TODO: 英語記事へのリンクをなるべく日本語にする

Comment: TODO: ヘルプページから英語版へのリンクを日本語版に置き換える https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、[ヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)リンクの日本語版への置き換え作業が完了しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 投稿はどのようにして削除されますか？

#### ユーザーが削除する場合:

1. **投稿者自身**は基本的に自分の投稿を自分で削除できます。例外的に削除できない場合については、下の項目「自分の投稿を削除できないのはどんな場合ですか？」をご覧ください。自分の投稿を削除するには、単に投稿下の「削除」を使います。
2. **モデレーター**は任意の投稿をすぐ削除できます。
3. **信用度1,000以上のユーザー**（正確には[編集権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)を持ったユーザー。ベータサイトでは1,000以上、通常サイトでは2,000以上のユーザー）は、「低品質な投稿」レビューキューの「削除」ボタンを選ぶことで投稿の自動削除に投票できます。下の14番の項目や[こちらの投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/152859)（英語）もあわせてご覧ください。
4. **信用度2,000以上のユーザー**（正確には[モデレーターツールへのアクセス権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)を持ったユーザー。ベータサイトでは2,000以上、通常サイトでは10,000以上のユーザー）は、[クローズ または 重複](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question)としてマークされて48時間以内の**質問**に対し、削除票を投じることができます。通常3票集まると削除されます。[人気の質問に対してはより票数が必要](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071)ですが、最大でも10票で削除されます。
5. **信用度4,000以上のユーザー**（正確には[「信頼できるユーザー」権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)を持ったユーザー。ベータサイトでは4,000以上、通常サイトでは20,000以上のユーザー）は、スコアが-3以下のクローズ済み質問に削除票を投じれます。これには48時間の制限がありません。また、スコアが-1以下の**回答**に対しても削除票を投じる事ができます。自己回答でなければ[承認された回答であっても構いません](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286049)。削除には3票が必要です。

#### システムが削除する場合:

6. [システム](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)は、「失礼又は暴言」であるとして6回[通報](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)された投稿を自動削除します（[English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/a-temporary-tweak-to-work-around-abusive-posting-patterns)と[The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/temporary-anti-spam-measures-are-now-in-place)においては3回です）。
7. システムは、ロックされていないクローズ済み質問で、スコアが0以下であり、スコアがプラスの回答や承認された回答がついておらず、有効な再オープン票が無く、重複以外の理由で9日以上前にクローズされており、かつ過去9日間に編集されていない質問を[自動削除](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)します。（`RemoveAbandonedClosed`）
8. システムは、移行が拒否され（つまり、他のサイトから移行された結果生まれた質問であって、その後重複以外の理由でクローズされており）30日間以上残っている質問を[自動削除](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)します。（`RemoveRejectedMigrations`）
9. システムは、スコアがマイナスで、ロックされておらず、かつ回答が集まっていないまま30日以上残っている質問を[自動削除](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)します。（`RemoveDeadQuestions`）
10. システムは、ロックされておらず、回答が無く、365日より長く残っているメインサイトの（メタではない）質問であって、スコアがゼロの（あるいは投稿者のアカウントが削除されている場合は1の）、日平均の閲覧回数が1.5未満かつコメントが2未満のものを[自動削除](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)します。（`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`）
11. システムは、メインサイトへ投稿されたスコアがマイナスの投稿を、その投稿者のアカウントが削除されたときに[自動削除](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote)します。ただしその投稿が少なくともひとつスコアがプラスの回答を集めていた場合は、削除されません。
12. システムは、[破棄（destroy）](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)されたアカウントが投稿した全ての投稿を、スコアの大小や回答の有無に関わらず自動削除します。これはスパマーや荒らしアカウントに対してのみ行われます。
13. システムは、移行元の質問（他のサイトに移行され拒否されなかった質問が元のサイトに残すコピーのこと）であって30日以上残ったものを[自動削除](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082)します。この条件で削除された質問は、削除されたといっても編集履歴は全員が閲覧できます。またこの質問へのリンクはエラーにならず、移行先の質問へリダイレクトします。（`RemoveMigrationStubs`）
14. スコアが0以下で、「低品質な投稿」レビューにより6つ（英語版Stack Overflowでは4つ）の削除票を集めた投稿は、「レビューによって削除された投稿」として自動削除されます。それぞれの投稿は、自動的に、あるいは「品質が低すぎる」「回答になっていません」という通報によって、「低品質な投稿」レビューキューに入れられます。そして十分な数の「良い」票を集めるとキューから外されます。

#### 関連する投稿が削除された場合:

15. 質問が削除されると、質問に対する回答もすべて削除されます。

こちらもご覧ください: [私の質問がコミュニティ♦︎ユーザーに削除されたのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) -- ヘルプセンター

### 自分の投稿を削除**できない**のはどんな場合ですか？

**注意:** iOSまたはAndroidのアプリでは自分の投稿を削除することができません。下に書かれている条件を満たさないのであれば、アプリのオプションからウェブブラウザで質問を開き、そこで削除を行ってください。

自分の**回答**は、それが[承認](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)されている場合、自分で削除することはできません。

自分の**質問**は、以下の条件を満たしている場合、自分で削除することはできません。

- [誰かがupvoteした回答がついている場合](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471)（その回答のスコア合計がゼロ以下であっても削除できません）
- 承認された回答がついている場合
- 複数の回答がついている場合（upvoteが一切無くても削除できません）
- [「懸賞」のついた回答がついている場合](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele)

自分のアカウントを登録していない場合（つまり、Google アカウント、Facebook アカウント、または Stack Exchange アカウントのどれとも紐付けていない場合）、自分のどの質問も回答も削除できません。

### 削除後も自分の投稿を見れますか？

モデレーターツールへのアクセス権限（ベータサイトでは信用度2,000以上、通常サイトでは10,000以上）を持っていれば、任意の質問のURLに直接アクセスすることによって、削除された質問も回答も全て見ることができます。ただし、もしその投稿がスパムや暴言として削除されたのであれば、本文を直接見ることはできません。編集履歴を辿ると見ることができます。

モデレーターツールへのアクセス権限を持っていないのであれば、質問のURLに直接アクセスすることによって、削除された自分の質問や回答については見ることができます。また、自分が回答した削除済み質問を見ることもできますが、他の方の回答や質問の編集履歴を見ることはできません。

### 削除された自分の投稿一覧を見れますか？

はい、ただし[**過去60日以内に作成されたもの**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile)のみです。もしモデレーターツールへのアクセス権限を持っているなら、`deleted:1`を使うことによって[自分の削除された投稿から検索できます](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users)。この権限が無いユーザーは、削除された自分の全ての投稿の一覧は[得られないでしょう](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)。

### 自分の投稿の削除を取り消すにはどうすればよいですか？

自分で削除した投稿は自分で削除を取り消すことができます。ただし[スパムを防ぐため](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296101/349538)、自分で削除した質問は、先に削除を取り消さないと自分で編集することはできません。自分で削除した回答については取り消さずとも編集できます。

自分の投稿が自分以外によって削除された場合、通常それを自分で取り消すことはできません（ただしモデレーターによって削除された訳でなければ、削除の取り消し票を投じることはできます）。例外として、「低品質な投稿」レビューキューの「削除」票によって回答が削除されたものの、その票が3人の「信頼できるユーザー」によるものではなかった場合、自分で[削除を取り消すことができます](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/259867)。

自分の投稿が[信頼できるユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)や[コミュニティ♦︎ユーザー](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214252/how-can-a-question-deleted-by-community-be-undeleted)によって削除された場合、削除の取り消しには3票の取り消し票が必要です。もし削除を取り消すべき良い理由があるのであれば、メタサイトで投票を丁寧にお願いするのが良いでしょう。もしその質問がコミュニティ♦︎ユーザーによって削除されたのであれば、再び削除条件に当てはまらないようにしておく必要があることに注意してください。何もしなかった場合、即座に再削除されてしまいます。

自分の投稿がモデレーターによって削除された場合、その投稿を通報し、「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」を選択し、そこで状況を説明した上で削除の取り消しを依頼してください。

注意: 削除された質問は検索結果に現れないため、質問の削除を後から取り消したい場合、どこかにその投稿のURLを保存していないといけません。モデレーターツールへのアクセス権限を持ったユーザーは、質問を「ブックマーク」しておけば後から自分のプロフィールページのブックマークタブから探せます。唯一モデレーターに限って、他のユーザーの削除された投稿を検索することができます。（モデレーターツールへのアクセス権限を持ったユーザーは[削除された自分の投稿を検索することはできます](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214252/how-can-a-question-deleted-by-community-be-undeleted)。）

投稿されてから60日以内の削除済み投稿は[「削除された最近の質問」「削除された最近の回答」](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/)に一覧表示されます。

### 投稿が削除されるとは**実際には**どういうことですか？

削除された投稿は基本的に物理的には削除されて**いません**。つまり、システム上から消え去っているわけではなく、単に隠されただけです（soft-delete ということです）。削除済み投稿は検索結果やデータダンプには現れませんし、通常のユーザーがその投稿へのリンクを辿っても[404（not found）ページが出ます](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2)。削除された回答へのリンクはそれが投稿された質問へリダイレクトします。削除された質問へのリンクは投稿者が削除したのであれば「作成者によって自主的に削除されました」と表示し、他の理由で削除されたのであれば「モデレーション上の理由により[site]から削除されました」と表示します。

モデレーター及び「モデレーターツールへのアクセス権限」を持った（このサイトでは信用度2,000以上の）通常ユーザーは、自分でリンクを知っている全ての削除済み投稿を見ることができます。それより信用度が低いユーザーは自分の削除済み投稿を見ることができます。モデレーターは全ての削除済み投稿の削除を取り消せます。

いわゆる「10kユーザー」（このサイトにおいては信用度2,000以上のユーザー）は削除された**質問**の削除取り消し票を投じれます。通常取り消しには3票必要であり、例外的に[もっと必要な場合もあります](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/259867)。

いわゆる「20kユーザー」（このサイトにおいては信用度4,000以上のユーザー）は削除された**回答**の削除取り消し票を投じれます。取り消しには3票が必要です。

### 削除された投稿について他に知っておくべきことは何ですか？

- 削除された投稿に対して行われていた懸賞、投票（upvoteもdownvoteも）、そして承認によって発生した信用度が無効化されます。（2つ例外があります。1つ目に、スコア3以上の投稿であり、サイト上で60日以上閲覧できた投稿から得た信用度であれば[そのままになります](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)。2つ目に、懸賞を授与された回答であって、1つ目の例外の条件を満たすものなら、懸賞によって得た信用度はそのままになります。）
- スパムか「失礼又は暴言」という通報によって投稿が削除されたことによるペナルティとして失われた信用度は、モデレーターが手動でスパム通報や暴言通報を削除しない限り戻ってきません。この状況は、投稿が謝って削除された場合に限ります（たとえばモデレーターが間違ってボタンを押してしまったときや、複数のユーザーが[投稿を削除しようと企んだとき](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223297/what-if-six-users-conspire-to-nuke-posts-with-spam-flags)です）。
- 初めてスコア3以上の自分の投稿を削除したとき、[「完璧主義」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)を得ます。
- 初めてスコア-3以下の自分の投稿を削除したとき、[「察する力」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)を得ます。
- 質問が削除されたとき、それについていた回答は自動削除されます。これらの回答の削除は、その質問の削除が取り消されたとき自動的に取り消されます。質問が削除されるより前に削除されていた回答はそうはなりません。

### 削除投票をするとどうなりますか？

- [削除投票の権限（モデレーターツールへのアクセス権限の一部です）](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)を持っている（ベータサイトでは2,000信用度、通常サイトでは10,000信用度以上の）ユーザーは、1日に5つの削除票を投じれます。更に、[その信用度から1,000信用度ごとに追加で1つの票を得ます](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-de/105876#105876)（[最大で30票/日です](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)）。自分の投稿への削除票は、状況によって[この制限に数えられたり数えられなかったりします](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274757/3717023)。
- 削除取り消し票は、削除票と同じ数だけ使えます。
- 削除票や削除取り消し票の有効期限はありません。

### 削除される条件は何ですか？

質問については、[サイトに対して何の情報も追加していないもの](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/148099)は削除されるべきです。これ以上改善できず再オープンもできないようなクローズ済み質問の多くは基本的にこれに当たります。しかしながら、重複した質問は削除されません。これは、よくある質問を探そうとした将来のユーザーが、言葉遣いが異なったために検索で上手く探せないことを防ぐためです。

回答については、[回答でない](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/148099)投稿は削除されるべきです（たとえば、コメントにすべきものや、質問に答えていないものなどです）。間違った回答や貧弱な回答は[削除するのではなくdownvoteすべきです](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264294/1)。

他にもいくつか一般的なガイドラインが存在します。ネットワーク上のいくつかのコミュニティでは、投稿の削除に関する具体的な理由を他にも掲げています。たとえばPuzzling.SEでは[説明無しでパズルに答えている回答は削除対象です](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/should-we-delete-answers-that-contain-no-explanation)し、いくつかの技術系サイトでは、間違っているだけでなく試すと危険であるような回答は削除されます。

### もし自分の質問を削除するように通報した場合、どうなりますか？

モデレーターの基本的なルールとしては、そのような通報は拒否されます。理由は以下の通りです。

- もし自分で自分の質問を削除できるなら（つまり回答が無かったり、upvoteの無い回答しか無かったりするなら）、自分で削除すべきです。モデレーターの介入は必要ありません。もしモバイルアプリを使っていて削除ができないなら、「more」を押して質問をウェブブラウザで開き、そこで削除できます。
- もし自分で自分の質問を削除できなかったのであれば、そこにはupvoteされた回答か、複数の回答か、あるいは懸賞を授与された回答があるはずです。質問を削除すると同時にこれらの回答も削除されてしまいます。これらの回答を削除してしまうと、他人がその質問に答えるためにかかった様々な苦労が水の泡になってしまうわけです。また、回答者が得た信用度も無しになってしまいます。これは回答者にとってフェアでありません。

もしあなたが、以下の理由で投稿したことを後悔しているなら……

- もともと学校の宿題であり、学校の倫理規定を破ってしまった
- ひどい質問で、恥ずかしい

……もしそうなら、質問を削除しても解決になりません。信用度2,000以上のユーザー（通常サイトでは10,000以上のユーザー）は結局その投稿を見れるからです。これは[Public Network Terms of Service（6章）でも明らかです](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public)。

> You agree that any and all content, ... that you provide to the public Network (collectively, "Subscriber Content"), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to [Creative Commons licensing terms (CC-BY-SA)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you as reasonably necessary ...

モデレーターは上のような理由では質問を削除しません。

その代わり、[質問とアカウントの紐付けを解除する](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/349538)ことができます。

#### 社員に著作権があるコードを投稿してしまったり、質問に著作権違反があるなどして、法的な理由から削除しなくてはいけないときにはどうすれば良いですか？

Stack ExchangeはDMCAに従ったテイクダウン処理を実装しています。もしあなたが著作権保持者であり、誰かがあなたの著作権を侵害するような内容の投稿をしている場合、[テイクダウンを報告することでそれは削除されます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy)。

「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」として通報するのは正しい方法ではありません。

#### うっかりログイン用のクレデンシャル情報などのセンシティブな情報を投稿してしまったらどうすれば良いですか？

このような場合、まずは質問と回答からその部分を同様の役割を果たすダミーテキスト/データ/コードで置き換えてください。おおまかなやり方が[ここ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278716/208518)や[ここ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327145/1328704)に（英語で）書かれています。**特に回答が既にある場合、投稿の文脈を崩さないように注意してください**。これらが済んだ後「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」として通報すると、モデレーターによって編集履歴が修正（redact）されます。

#### 例外はありますか？

場合によっては例外があります。多くの場合例外は以下のようなときに起こります。

- すべての回答が60日以上残っており、3以上のスコアがあるとき（回答のついた質問が削除されないための仕組みがあるので回答者は信用度を失いませんが、これらの条件が満たされるなら削除されても信用度は失われないので、議論の余地があります）
- この回答でカバーできていない質問や回答がどう扱われるかよく分かっていません