# 第3回もくもく会 : 既存のナレッジベースを改善しましょう！

Tags: 討議, 交流会, もくもく会

2021年3月に、もくもく会を開催できることを大変嬉しく思います！前回に引き続き、今回も nekketsuuu さんと payaneco さんがイベントを主導くださいます。

**開催日時 :**
1日目 ファシリテーター : [payaneco](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco)さん
2021年3月6日（土）13:00 - 17:00

2日目 ファシリテーター : [nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)さん
2021年3月7日（日）13:00 - 17:00

**集合場所 :**
[SOja交流会チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja)です。途中入退室 OKです。

**スケジュール ：**
13:00 - 13:30 開会式 -> ゆるりと集まって「今日の目標」を宣言する
15:00 - 15:30 休憩時間 -> ほっこりしましょう〜、もぐもぐしたり、甘味報告など
16:30 - 17:00 閉会式および反省会 ->「今日の成果」や「感想」を適当に書き込む

**どなたでもご参加いただけます！**
*コミュニティのナレッジベースは多くの人々の小さな貢献によって改善されます*。時間に余裕がありコミュニティをサポートできるというかたがおられましたら次の様な貢献の方法をご紹介させてください :

- *既存の回答に改善編集を提案*。投稿に関するAPIの変更やSDKの更新があった場合、回答を正確かつ適切な状態に保つために編集を提案してみましょう。
- *新しい回答を投稿*。いくつかの質問には、まだ (承認された) 回答が付いていないものがあります。これらに回答を投稿してみましょう。
- *関連性の低い質問や回答を削除* : 投稿内容が古くなったり品質が低いものについて、コミュニティーメンバーによる投稿の改善も難しい場合には、それらを削除して整理することも検討してください。

回答や改善できる質問を見つけるための最も簡単な方法として、[未回答の質問にソート](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)することがあげられます。:

1. 質問のクオリティが高い場合 :

   - 良い回答が付いている場合には、その回答にプラス票を投じる。
   - 回答がない、または何か問題がある場合は、自分で回答を投稿してください。
2. 質問のクオリティが低い場合 :

   - 改善できる場合には、編集提案をして ステップ1 に戻る。
   - 改善が難しい場合には、マイナス票を投じるか "質問のクローズ" に投票する。
     (その後、 [放棄された投稿を削除するのは コミュニティユーザー のお仕事です](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba))。

#### ナレッジベースを良くするためにはあなたのサポートが必要です！

まとまった時間を用意してみんなで一人ひとり何かに取り組むことがもくもく会の目標ですので、スタック・オーバーフローに関することなら基本的に何をしてもOKです。

ぜひご参加ください！一緒にコミュニティのナレッジベースを改善しましょう。

Answer (score 4):

### Good First Issue

折角なので、やりたいことが見つからない方向けに、TODO リストのようなものを作ってみました。

#### 自分の普段からの疑問を質問にする

スタック・オーバーフローでは「良い質問」は「良い回答」と同じく重要です。自分の中でまだ解決していない問題を質問として投稿してみるのはいかがでしょうか。もくもく会で注目があつまっている時期ですし、ちょうど回答が付くかもしれません。

#### 自分の得意分野の回答をする

普段なかなか時間が取れずに書けていなかった回答を書く時間とするのに、もくもく会は便利です。何かひとつ回答するのを目標に書いてみるのはいかがでしょうか。

また、[タグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags)から未解決の質問を見つけて回答するのも良いでしょう。[「蘇生術」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/64/revival)や[「復活の呪文」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)獲得のチャンスです。

#### 自分の得意分野の質問や回答を見て回る

[タグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags)から特定の分野の質問や回答を見て回り、良い投稿があればプラス投票をするのはいかがでしょうか。良い投稿にたくさんのプラス投票が集まれば、一覧したとき上の方に並ぶことが増え、誰かが同じような問題で悩んだときその投稿に巡り合う確率を上げることができます。

もしイマイチな投稿があれば、編集の提案を行うことができます。それが回答の場合、自分で新しくもっと良い回答を書くのもアリでしょう。既存の回答にたくさんプラス投票が集まっていてもお気になさらず。[「みんなが選んだ」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist)の獲得チャンスです。

#### タグ wiki を書く

新しい技術の登場に伴い、スタック・オーバーフローでは新しいタグが増え続けています。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags からタグの一覧を見ることができますが、いくつかページをめくるとタグ wiki の抜粋が無かったり、抜粋があってもタグ wiki は無かったりするものが散見されます。しかしタグ wiki は質問者がどのタグを付ければ良いか考える際に見る重要な場所です。

そのタグがどんなときに使われるべきか明確にするためにも、タグ wiki を充実させていくのはいかがでしょうか。

#### サイトを翻訳する

スタック・オーバーフローのサイトは日夜変化しています。その結果、サイトの随所に英語が残ってしまっています。

実はそういった英語の和訳は、コミュニティがボランティアで行っています。スタック・オーバーフローのユーザーなら誰でも https://ja.traducir.win/ から翻訳の提案を行えます。もくもく会の時間を使って、残っている英語を一掃するのは如何でしょうか。

ただし、[専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/19110)の和訳をすることが良くあるので、スタック・オーバーフローの仕組みにある程度慣れている方にオススメです。

Answer (score 4):

私からもTODOリストの案を。

#### コメントを整理

質問や回答にはコメントを付けることができますが、これはあくまで "付箋" のような位置づけです。
主に投稿内容の明確化を求める場合などに用いますが、重要な内容は必要に応じて投稿の本文に反映されるべきです。

役目を終えたコメント (既に本文に転記済み、もしくはあなたが編集して転記した) については、通報フラグを使ってモデレーターにお知らせください。

#### 削除された投稿の確認

[投稿の削除には色々な条件](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2869) がありますが、「あなたが投稿した回答が "質問の削除" に関連して削除」されているケースが時折あるようです。

恐らく質問者本人が解決して用済みになった質問を削除してしまうようなのですが、ナレッジの蓄積という観点でこのような行動は好ましくありません。

「評価の低い質問」や「問題のある質問」等を場合を除いて、"削除されるべきではない" と思われる質問や回答を見つけた場合には "削除の取り消し" 票を入れてみてください。

検索欄に `deleted:1 user:me` と入力することで、自分自身の投稿で削除されたものが検索できます。
自分の投稿で意図せず削除されたものが無いかを点検してみてください。

Comment: `deleted:1`が無視される場合は自分のユーザーページのアクティビティタブを開き、その中の回答タブを選択すると下部に 最近削除された回答 へのアンカーがあります。このページでは直近60日の間に削除された回答が表示されます。