# 第3回もくもく会を開始します！ → 開催しました！

Tags: 討議, 交流会, もくもく会

調和を保ちながらコミュニティのナレッジベースの質を維持するのは簡単なことではありません。しかし私たちは今日ここに集まりプログラミング愛好家の素晴らしいコミュニティとして力を合わせることができます✊。

みなさん、こんにちは！[第3回もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3490/78)でお会いできることを大変嬉しく思います。この2日間で、力を合わせてナレッジベースを改善していきましょう！イベントのファシリテーターは前回に引き続きまして[@payaneco さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco)と[@nekketsuuu さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)です。
私たちの共有の目標を達成する方法の1つとして、[未解決の質問タブ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)をクリックし、以下を行うことができます :

1. 質の高い質問である場合 :

   - 良い回答が付いている場合には、その回答にプラス票を投じる。
   - まだ回答が無い場合や質の低い回答しかない場合には、新しい回答を投稿する。
2. 質の低い質問である場合 :

   - 改善できる場合には、編集提案をして ステップ1 に戻る。
   - 改善が難しい場合には、マイナス票を投じるか "質問のクローズ" に投票する。
     (その後、放棄された投稿を削除するのは[コミュニティユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) のお仕事です。

全ての小さな貢献に感謝します。1つの回答や1つの投票が知識ベースをより良いものにしていきます。そしてそれが勝利へとつながるのです。

もくもく会でアドバイスを共有したり、仲間と交流したい場合には、[SOja交流会チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja)で行ってください。

お忙しい中ご参加いただけますこと本当に嬉しく思います。頑張ってやってみましょう！ =）

Answer (score 4):

私たちが集まり、ナレッジベースの改善に取り組めたのは素晴らしいことです。もくもく会の2日間では、次の活動が行われました :

- 36 件の回答
- 145 回の投票

私たちはこのような活動に誇りを持つべきだと思います。参加してくれた皆さん、どうもありがとう！ファシリテーター役の@payaneco さんと@nekketsuuu さんに感謝を申し上げます！素晴らしいファシリテーションをありがとうございました！
ぜひまた、開催しましょう

Comment: もくもく会の開催を提案してくださり、まとめてくださった @aki さんにも感謝申し上げます！

Comment: Sorry for misinformation on the number of votes. It seems that somehow I calculated only downvotes last time.（投票数に関する誤った情報を一旦掲載してしまい心よりお詫び申し上げます。どういうわけかマイナス投票の数だけを計算してしまったようです。）

Comment: イベント結果の集計ありがとうございます！参加者の皆さんと素晴らしい時間を共有できました素敵なイベントを開いてくださって、とても楽しかったです