# もくもく会の開催時間の長短についてご意見をください

Tags: 討議, 交流会, もくもく会

今までスタック・オーバーフローではもくもく会を 3 回開催してきました。

3 回目となる [2021 年 3 月のもくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3490/19110)では、以下のスケジュールでもくもく作業をする時間としました。

- 2021 年 3 月 6 日（土）13:00 - 17:00
- 2021 年 3 月 7 日（日）13:00 - 17:00

一応途中参加・途中退出自由ということにした上での時間設定なのですが、それでもちょっと長いのでは、という意見が見られました。

実際充分な Q&A やモデレーションを行おうとするとこれでも時間が足りなかったりするのですが、とはいえ「ちょっとだけ活動したい」という要望に応えるには長すぎる時間かもしれません。

そこで、もし次回のもくもく会を開催するとしたらどのくらいの時間が良いかご意見を募集したいです。もっと長い方が良いでしょうか、短い方が良いでしょうか？　日程は 1 日だけの方が集中できて良かったでしょうか？

参加できた方に加えて、参加できなかった方からのご意見も伺いたいです。よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 2):

期間２日がちょうど良いです。
今回私は土曜と、日曜日少しだけ参加できました。
もし開催日が日曜だけだったら、気の済むまで活動できなかったと思います。
次回もぜひ参加したいと考えていますが、都合がつかないこともあります。期間は１日よりも２日の方がありがたいです。
期間が長ければ参加できる可能性は増えますが、「いつでも参加できる」と思うと、かえって参加する意欲が薄れるかもしれません。
期間が１日の方が「参加したい気持ち」が強くなるのは確かですが、参加できないリスクを考えると、個人的には２日間がちょうどよい期間だと思います。

Answer (score 2):

[第1回もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3235)は13:00-16:00でした。
[第2回もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3358)にもっと長時間の提案やもぐもぐタイムの提案がなされて第3回も踏襲されました。

今まで3回参加してきた私個人の意見としては、2日間開催はどちらかに参加可能であり、作業時間的にも**ちょうど良い時間配分**だと思っています。
実際に作業を始めると動作検証や文章の推敲など、どこかで絶対につまづくのでむしろ時間が足りないくらいですが、それも含めてちょうど良いです。

ただし私はどちらか片方の日程に予定が入っていることが多いので、上記の感想なのかもしれません。
2日間のフル参加を想像して「休日午後を両日とも使う」となると、気合か栄養ドリンクを注入したくなる…方もいるのでしょうか？

時間をずらしつつ短くして、例えば「**土曜日の20:00-23:00と日曜日の13:00-16:00**」にすると参加しやすい方が増えるならば、試すのも有益だと思います。
私は日中の方が参加しやすいので、他の方の回答やコメントで反応をいただけると嬉しいです。

少し話がずれますが、これまでに何度か「もくもく会の趣旨が分からない」という反応をいただいた点は改善の余地があるかもしれません。
SOjaもくもく会のGood First Issue、チャットルームの使い方、過去の実績などから**参加者に取り組んでほしい具体的な行動**を簡単かつ明確に提示するのが良いでしょうか。

イベントの趣旨や目的はMeta投稿で十分に示していただいていると思います。
次は新参の方に動線を敷いて参加の障壁をなくすことで、チャットルームのアクティブ数が上がるのではないかと期待しています。

個人的にもくもく会に1度でも参加してしまえば雰囲気が分かると思いますし、マニュアルで発想の幅を狭めたくないとも思っています。
しかしそれよりも門戸を広げて誰でも参加できる地盤作りの方がきっと大事だと信じています。