# Happy New Year 2022!

Tags: 討議

翻訳をしてくれた[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)に感謝します。

---

#### 数字で振り返る 1 年

| 日本語版スタック・オーバーフロー | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 質問 | 5563 | 4228 |
| 回答 | 4452 | 3184 |
| 新規ユーザー | 4933 | 5167 |

<sup>*削除されたものも含めた絶対数です。</sup>

#### 未来に寄せて

今年、[Stack Overflow は Prosus の傘下になりました](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/)。法務的な手続きの後、我々は採用活動を更に強化しました。その結果現在までに Community Management チームは 13 人となり、これからも更にたくさんの仲間が[チームに加わってくれるでしょう](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3726372/staff-community-manager-collectives)。同じ様なことは Public Platform チーム（このサイトのソフトウェアを開発しているチーム）にも起こっています。これによって以前から議論している便利な提案がより多く実装できることになり、コミュニティとコンテンツをモデレーションするためのツールがたくさん作られるだろうと私は考えています。

来たる年が、とても楽しみです！ =)

#### お祝いしましょう！

さて、では、1 年を締めくくり、次なる年を迎えましょう！　是非お祝いに参加してください。あなたがコミュニティの中で経験した楽しかったことや嬉しかったことを、是非共有してください。あるいはもし今年他のユーザーが何かしら素晴らしいことをしていたのなら、是非この質問に回答としてご共有ください。きっと皆さん喜んでくれると思います。

2022 年が、私たちにとって幸せな年になることを願っています！

Answer (score 10):

[supa さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/32986/supa)の翻訳への協力に感謝したいです。昨年に引き続き、[Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/) を使った翻訳はもちろん、翻訳システムの不具合についてメタに投稿することまで、supa さんは貢献してくださいました。

メタへの打ち上げという意味ですと、[cubick さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)にも感謝したいです。日本語版メタへの打ち上げを、必要に応じて [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) に英語で転載し、問題提起を行ってくださいました。

そしてもちろん、[aki さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)にも感謝の意を表します。多くの重要な string が高速に翻訳されていったのは aki さんのおかげです。

今年も何回かシステムの string 管理がぶっ壊れてサイト上に英語が露出しましたが、その度に直っているのは協力して翻訳を行っているコミュニティのおかげです。皆さんありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4):

2021年度も、2020年に引き続きコミュニティ主導のもとコロナ禍の中でオンラインイベントを行うことができました。[第3回もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3490/14055)をファシリテートくださった [@payaneco さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco) と [@nekketsuuu さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) 、いつも陰で支えてくださるモデレーションチーム、そして参加くださったみなさんに心より感謝申し上げます。

交流会はそもそも必要あるのか、と不思議に思われている方もおられるのかもしれないので、私が個人的に意義があると思う理由を少しシェアさせてください。ナレッジベースの改善活動を行われているユーザーのみなさんはもちろん bot などではなく human です。体調が優れている日もあればそうでない日もあり、さまざまな場所からあらゆるコンディションの方がスタック・オーバーフローに参加されています。メインサイトではコードや書式等にフォーカスをおいて機械的なコミュニケーションになってしまうケースも全くないとは言えません。

交流会で人とふれある機会を持つことはコミュニティに良い影響を与えられるのではないかと考えます。なぜなら、ナレッジベース改善のための交流会を通じて、日本語話者のプログラマー仲間たちに寄り添えるコミュニティづくりをファシリテーターさんや参加者の方がコミュニティ全体に無理なく示すことができるからです。

﻿今年はコロナ禍終息の年になるかもしれないと希望を持っています。そして、7周年(Beta卒業)記念オンラインイベントもその2022年に開催できることを楽しみにしています  。