# 未翻訳：質問一覧の上のカテゴリー

Tags: バグ, サポート, 翻訳

質問一覧の上に、新着、定期的な質問、お礼を付与された質問などのカテゴリー選択欄がありますが、お礼と定期的にが、`Featured`, `Freqent`, `Hot`など、未翻訳のカテゴリーが表示されるようになっているみたいです。

Answer (score 3):

「Frequent：リンク最多」「Hot：人気」は今まで通りに、Featured は「注目」と訳すのはいかがでしょうか？

#### 追記 (2019年4月16日)

反対意見が無いようでしたので、翻訳案を Traducir で提案してみました。とりあえず上の訳が反映されます。他意見あれば回答またはコメント頂ければ後からでも変えられます :)

Comment: 「必見」というワードが浮かびました。しかし「注目」のほうが個人的なしっくり度が高いです。

Comment: 「バウンティ付きの目玉質問」というような意味合いで何か短く良いワードがないものかと考えましたが何も頭に浮かびませんでした。「目玉」という響きはいささかエレガンスに欠けるように思えたので、やはり「注目」がよろしいのでしょうか :)

Answer (score 1):

これまでは以下のように訳されていたようです。コミュニティで意見がまとまりましたら、ぜひ翻訳をみなさんで更新してくださいね！[Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/)は日本語版の翻訳に興味のある方は誰でもご参加いただけます♬

Featured : おすすめ
https://ja.traducir.win/string/10691

Frequent : リンク最多
https://ja.traducir.win/string/10727

Hot : 人気
https://ja.traducir.win/string/10701

Comment: 気がついたので報告しただけですので、急ぐ人はいないと思います。慌てぬようお願いします

Comment: 他の用語との兼ね合いもあるので整合をとるのが難しいですが、[「おすすめ」だと分かりづらいかもしれないという提案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2650/3060)を過去にしています。代わりの案が特に出ていないのでとりあえずは「おすすめ」でいいのかもしれませんが。

Comment: せっかくなので、一旦入力を取り消しましょうか？英語のままにしておいて、コミュニティでちょっと考える時間があってよろしいのかもしれませんね♬

Comment: 英語に戻しました m_ _m